# IE and Chrome don't fire a mouseover event for <option> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

My code only works in Firefox. Why is this?

HTML:

```
<select id="selecter">
         <option>one</option>
         <option>two</option>
         <option>three</option>
   </select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on("mouseover", "#selecter option",function(){
            alert(1)        
    });
});
```

I'm curious why IE and chrome don't fire a mouseover event. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yT6Y5/72/ (Works perfectly in Firefox.)

How can I get IE and Chrome to fire a mouseover event?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that browsers render dropdowns differently. Chrome is rendering it not as an HTML component but as a native GUI one. That can't have hover handlers associated to it from JS.

If you want to make sure it works on all browsers either don't use a dropdown or get a script to create a dropdown that uses HTML elements

Comment: @PCoelho thanks for your information.. strange behavior..is't?? can please tell me any other area which having the same rendering issue.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems, no events are actually fired when you hover over an option in IE & chrome,

At best should should bind on the change event.

```
$(function() {
    $("#selecter").change(function(){
            alert(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you should use , a different approach to bind the event

```
 $(function() {
    $("#selecter").mouseover(function(){
        alert(1)        
     });
  });
```

Comment: mouseover will not work in chrome either way if you assign onmouseover to each option even then it wont work in chrome..because i think chrome does not support mouseover.

Comment: which is not firing either try this on ie or chrome http://jsfiddle.net/yT6Y5/73/ .....thanx

Comment: then you can try change event instead