# Hovering over option in a select list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, tooltip

I am trying to trigger "bootstrap tooltiop" on hover over an `<option>` in `<select>`.

In FF it works as expected, but in Chrome works only if the size properties of `<select>` has been added(?) and in IE doesn't work at all.

is there a way to make it works in Chrome without "size"?

here the HTML:

```
<select class="ddl" size="4" data-toggle="tooltip">                         
    <option data-title="1" value="jedan" selected>jedan</option>
    <option data-title="2" value="dva"> dva </option>
    <option data-title="3" value="tri"> tri </option>
    <option data-title="4" value="cetri">cetri</option>
    <option data-title="5" value="pet">pet</option>
</select>

<select class="ddl" data-toggle="tooltip">                          
    <option data-title="1" value="jedan" selected>jedan</option>
    <option data-title="2" value="dva"> dva </option>
    <option data-title="3" value="tri"> tri </option>
    <option data-title="4" value="cetri">cetri</option>
    <option data-title="5" value="pet">pet</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var ddl = $(".ddl")

$(ddl).on('mouseover', "option",  function(e) {    
    var el = $(e.target); 
    var desc = el.data("title");
       ddl.tooltip('destroy');
        ddl.tooltip({
            placement: 'top',
            title: desc
        })
        .tooltip('show');

});
```

and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf4MH/1/)

Comment: Options don't generally trigger mouse events, and they generally shouldn't.

Comment: give up on this idea.. events for `<option>` tag are not supported in IE. Can't hide them either. If FF supports it, it is non standard behavior. Apart from style, this is a major reason many `select` replacement plugins have been created

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038811/why-ie-and-chrome-is-not-firing-on-mouseover-select-option

Comment: why does it work in chrome if the `size="x"` has been added, as in first example?

Comment: It happens because the options tags are not rendered in DOM. 
If size attribute is provided, it might work. You can better use some jquery plugins for select box like `http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/` or you can make your own div to achieve this functionality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE and Chrome don't fire a mouseover event for <option> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038811/ie-and-chrome-dont-fire-a-mouseover-event-for-option-elements)