# Javascript event doesn't fire when select box options have focus

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get something to happen (write to `div`) when a select box option has the focus. From the jsfiddle code, you can see I've got it working after the fact -- that is, once the option is selected and the mouse is moved back to the now-closed select box. How do I get it to work when the box is open?

(In case it matters, I have another function bound to the same element (the select box) that fires on a 'change' event. I wonder if that's the problem?).

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Hint"></div>
<div id='select-container'>
    <select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
        <option selected="selected">-- Select 1st option --</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
        <option value="">-- Select 2nd option --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
//Display hint for hovered selection in 1st dropdown
var elSelect_container, elHint; // Declare variables

elAppSelected = document.getElementById('parent_selection');
elHint = document.getElementById('Hint');

function Hint() {
    var elAppSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    if (elAppSelected === 'option1') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Good choice';
    }
    if (elAppSelected === 'option2') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Better choice';
    }
    if (elAppSelected === 'option3') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Best Choice!';
    }
}
    //Create event listener: mouseover calls Hint()
    elAppSelected.addEventListener('mouseover', Hint, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpt613/a8hxa1jm/30/

Comment: Option elements don't consistently support mouseover events. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038811/ie-and-chrome-dont-fire-a-mouseover-event-for-option-elements

Comment: But also there is some kind of workaround: http://dossett.org/11/No_onmouseover_for_options_in_IE/

Comment: Ah-ha! A clue. My code works in FF but not in Chrome or IE. Will investigate the workaround. Thanks Zentoaku.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the onchange event that is not shown. I changed addEventListener to change vs mouseover and the example works fine. I am not sure what u need the other onchange event for but maybe you can combine them.

**JavaScript:**

```
//Display hint for hovered selection in 1st dropdown
var elSelect_container, elHint; // Declare variables

elAppSelected = document.getElementById('parent_selection');
elHint = document.getElementById('Hint');

function Hint() {
    var elAppSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    if (elAppSelected === 'option1') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Good choice';
    }
    if (elAppSelected === 'option2') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Better choice';
    }
    if (elAppSelected === 'option3') {
        elHint.innerHTML = 'Best Choice!';
    }
}
    //Create event listener: mouseover calls Hint()
    elAppSelected.addEventListener('change', Hint, false);         
  //elAppSelected.addEventListener('mouseover', Hint, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8hxa1jm/31/

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your edit to my code does indeed work but it's not what I want. My fault. I guess I didn't explain the issue well enough. The result I'm after is akin to a tooltip. When a user of my site hovers on a select box option I want to present them some text (which goes in the hint div in my code), I realize I could attach a title attribute to the option to achieve the same thing. Or use a plugin like qtip or Jquery Tooltip. I may end up doing that if I can't get my own code to work but I'm pretty sure it won't be necessary what with all the expertise here. Again, thanks.